# Пытаюсь вывести данные из базы данных, а в итоге ошибка

Tags: php, mysql

Пытаюсь вывести данные из базы данных, а в итоге вот такая ошибка:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in J:\home\localhost\www\admin\section\page.php on line 5

Код php:

```
include "/../setting_sql.php";
$d_table=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'order'");
while($stroka=mysql_fetch_array($d_table)) 
{
     echo $stroka["id"]; 
     echo " <br>";
}
```

Comment: Функции `mysql_` являются устаревшими в `php`. Не используйте их!

Comment: И замените одинарные кавычки вокруг имени таблицы на апострофы.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй запустить этот код и посмотри какую ошибку выдаст

```
include "/../setting_sql.php";

$d_table=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'order'");

if($d_table) {
    while($stroka=mysql_fetch_array($d_table)) {
        echo $stroka["id"]; echo " <br>";
    }
}
else {
    print mysql_error();
}
```

P.S. Да и 'order' лучше заменить на order

Comment: order - ключевое слово, поэтому без экранирования из такой таблицы сделать выборку не получится

Answer (score 0):

замените `'order'` на `` `order` ``, проверьте, установилось ли соединенние с базой данных, как Вам написали выше, проблема где в одном из этих вариантов

Comment: Зря вы так написали. Парсер сожрал всю вашу мысль :D

Comment: используйте не одинарные кавычки, а те что на символе тильда ~

Comment: Они называются **апострофы**.